# (facebook) flow - how do type annotations work

Tags: javascript, typescript, annotations, flowtype

Facebook's Flow supports [type annotations](https://flowtype.org/docs/type-annotations.html#type-annotations). Specyfing types is something unavailable in JavaScript (and probably will never be, due to weak-typing nature of it) - and it is a major feature of [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) language.

My question is - how should one use Flow's type annotations in JavaScript code, knowing, that JS doesn't support type annotations - it's just something beyond the language.

My comment: surely, I could use yet another preprocessor of JS to remove the annotations (whether under grunt, gulp, webpack or whatever), but this is an extra step which makes automation more expensive. And that would seem very poor design to me, so I guess there might be a better explanation/solution than that.

Moreover, type annotations is a TypeScript feature. As flow supports it, does that mean that Flow's target is not only JavaScrpt, but also TypeScript? If so, then why should I use flow instead of TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of options here.

### Type Annotations

In either Flow or TypeScript, you can use type annotations, or use comments. If you don't use type annotations in TypeScript, you can just use the `--allowJs` flag and write your types in JS Doc comments per usual:

[image: AllowJS with TypeScript]

If you are using syntactic type annotations (e.g. `a: string`), you'll need to use Babel or TypeScript to remove them.

### ES6 features

If you're using ES6+ features like classes, imports, arrow functions, etc, and want to target ES5-compatible browsers, you'll need to use some transform step to turn those constructs into compatible code. Babel or TypeScript can both do this. Since Flow is usually chained in to Babel anyway, this is basically "free" the same way it is in TypeScript.

### TypeScript-specific features

If you want to use `enum` or `namespace`, which are TypeScript-specific, you'll have to use TypeScript. If you want to use Babel to do the ES6 transforms for you (maybe you have some plugins you want to run), you can chain the TypeScript ES6 output into Babel so that there's only one downleveling going on.

### Type System

Flow and TypeScript have somewhat different type systems. There are minor differences but nothing huge.

Proponents of each will show you examples that work in one but not the other, e.g.

```
var arr = [10, "ok"];
arr.pop();
arr.push(10);
arr[1].substr(1); // crashes
```

and

```
function square(x) { return x * x };
console.log(square('a hundred')); // prints NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Flow supports type annotations in javascript comments, but I'd imagine the largest argument for Flow as opposed to Typescript is that there is not much transformation going on. Your javascript stays the same, and you gain the benefits of static typing. Also If you read the documentation surrounding flow, it has its own way of removing the type annotations; think of it a bit like a compile.

Edit: It appears I was incorrect, that typescript also supports comment based annotations.

Comment: _it has its own way of removing the type annotations_ - and that's exactly what makes no sense to me, since TypeScript gives you very much, but it forces you to compile/transpile it. Flow is a static type checker, so why should I introduce a compile phase anyway? I undesrtand what you write, but I can't understand the concept. For now I see that FB wanted to have their exclusive tool competing with MS' and Google's TypeScript.

Comment: Well the removal of additional things, is very different from the transformation of things. Also as I said above you can keep your type annotations in javascript comments, as a way to totally remove the "removal process". However the really really important thing that I think you're missing is that my javascript stays the same.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't alter the JavaScript either. Maybe you should post some examples of where you think this happens?

Comment: Well anywhere you're using ES6 features, is probably more what I was thinking Ryan.

Comment: Since flow works outside of babel without doing any transformations via the type comments. This way one could augment existing javascript with type annotations without changing the type of file or adding any transformations. I don't personally use it but this is as far as I know something Flow does that Typescript does not.

Comment: With your first part of your answer I see that I was incorrect about typescripts ability to use comments. I'll leave my my answer up for historical reasons.

Comment: TypeScript won't transform your ES6 code if you're targeting ES6. And Flow code written using ES6 features won't run on an ES5 runtime, so the same transforms happen if run through Babel. Not really an apples-to-apples comparison if you're talking about ES5 code vs ES6->ES5 transformed code.

Comment: Right that makes sense, I thought I knew enough to make a contribution, sorry for muddying the water